# JSON to cell google sheet array work but object not working by binanace API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, binance, binance-api-client

this is Response:

```
{
 "makerCommission": 15,
 "takerCommission": 15,
 "buyerCommission": 0,
 "sellerCommission": 0,
 "canTrade": true,
 "canWithdraw": true,
 "canDeposit": true,
 "updateTime": 123456789,
 "accountType": "SPOT",
 "balances": [
   {
  "asset": "BTC",
  "free": "4723846.89208129",
  "locked": "0.00000000"
   },
   {
  "asset": "LTC",
  "free": "4763368.68006011",
  "locked": "0.00000000"
   }
            ],
  "permissions": [
  "SPOT"
  ]
 }
```

This is my code :

```
   var jsonResponce = JSON.parse(data); // To JSON
   Logger.log(jsonResponce.accountType); // Return SPOT

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var rows = [],
       balanc;

  for (i = 0; i < jsonResponce.length; i++) {
     balanc = jsonResponce[i];
     rows.push([balanc.accountType]);
    }
  Logger.log(rows); /////////////// return []  why not return SPOT
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 1);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
```

The JSON return accountType if run without array but after add in array give me [] empty any help pls.

this is picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7aif.jpg)

Comment: Where did you define `balancearray`? Please provide the complete code with sample input and your expected output

Comment: I'm sorry the `balancearray` is `jsonResponce` I change the code error thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunk() {
  const data = '{"makerCommission":15,"takerCommission":15,"buyerCommission":0,"sellerCommission":0,"canTrade":true,"canWithdraw":true,"canDeposit":true,"updateTime":123456789,"accountType":"SPOT","balances":[{"asset":"BTC","free":"4723846.89208129","locked":"0.00000000"},{"asset":"LTC","free":"4763368.68006011","locked":"0.00000000"}],"permissions":["SPOT"]}';
  const obj = JSON.parse(data);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = obj.balances;
  const oA = vs.map(obj => [obj.asset,obj.free,obj.locked]);
  sh.getRange(1,1,oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Sheet1:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BTC | 4723846.892 | 0 |
| LTC | 4763368.68 | 0 |

Comment: thanks This code is work but why about line `"makerCommission":15,"takerCommission":15,"buyerCommission":0,"sellerCommission":0,"canTrade":true,"canWithdraw":true,"canDeposit":true,"updateTime":123456789,"accountType":"SPOT"` but how if you want to add `"updateTime":123456789` or another item. I try like that but not work    `const oS = (obj => [obj.accountType]);
  sh.getRange(5,5,oS.length, oS[0].length).setValues(oS);` give me error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: obj is no longer json it's just a javascript so just like any other object update time is obj.updatetime.  accountType is obj.accountType.  I'm not familiar with this code structure `(obj => [obj.accountType]):` it makes no sense to me

Comment: Yes. your are right so do you know any method to put object `accountType` in sheet.

Comment: `sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(obj.accountType)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your `rows` is empty is because your `jsonResponce` is not an array. If you will log `jsonResponce.length` it will return `null`.

### Sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var jsonData = [{
 "makerCommission": 15,
 "takerCommission": 15,
 "buyerCommission": 0,
 "sellerCommission": 0,
 "canTrade": true,
 "canWithdraw": true,
 "canDeposit": true,
 "updateTime": 123456789,
 "accountType": "SPOT",
 "balances": [
   {
  "asset": "BTC",
  "free": "4723846.89208129",
  "locked": "0.00000000"
   },
   {
  "asset": "LTC",
  "free": "4763368.68006011",
  "locked": "0.00000000"
   }
            ],
  "permissions": [
  "SPOT"
  ]
 }];
  var data = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  var jsonResponce = JSON.parse(data); // To JSON
  Logger.log(jsonResponce); 
  Logger.log(Array.isArray(jsonResponce))
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   Logger.log(jsonResponce.length);
   var rows = [],
       balanc;

  for (i = 0; i < jsonResponce.length; i++) {
     balanc = jsonResponce[i];
     rows.push([balanc.accountType]);
    }
  Logger.log(rows); /////////////// return []  why not return SPOT
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 1);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
  
}
```

### Modifications done:

- create a json array. (encapsulate original json data with `[]`)

### Output:

```
6:37:31 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:37:31 AM  Info    [{canDeposit=true, sellerCommission=0.0, balances=[{locked=0.00000000, asset=BTC, free=4723846.89208129}, {locked=0.00000000, asset=LTC, free=4763368.68006011}], takerCommission=15.0, permissions=[SPOT], canTrade=true, makerCommission=15.0, updateTime=1.23456789E8, buyerCommission=0.0, accountType=SPOT, canWithdraw=true}]
6:37:32 AM  Info    1.0
6:37:32 AM  Info    [[SPOT]]
6:37:34 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

### Note:

You can use **[Array.isArray()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp)**, to check if the variable is an array or not then read the data accordingly.

### Sample:

```
  if(Array.isArray(jsonResponce)){
    for (i = 0; i < jsonResponce.length; i++) {
     balanc = jsonResponce[i];
     rows.push([balanc.accountType]);
    }
  }else{
    rows.push([jsonResponce.accountType])
  }
```

---

### (UPDATE)

If you want to make the Binance API response into an array, you can append "[" and "]" on your data.

### Sample:

```
 var jsonData = {
 "makerCommission": 15,
 "takerCommission": 15,
 "buyerCommission": 0,
 "sellerCommission": 0,
 "canTrade": true,
 "canWithdraw": true,
 "canDeposit": true,
 "updateTime": 123456789,
 "accountType": "SPOT",
 "balances": [
   {
  "asset": "BTC",
  "free": "4723846.89208129",
  "locked": "0.00000000"
   },
   {
  "asset": "LTC",
  "free": "4763368.68006011",
  "locked": "0.00000000"
   }
            ],
  "permissions": [
  "SPOT"
  ]
 };

  var data = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

  data = "["+data+"]";
  var jsonResponce = JSON.parse(data); // To JSON
  Logger.log(jsonResponce);
  Logger.log(Array.isArray(jsonResponce))
```

### Output:

```
12:21:48 AM Info    [{makerCommission=15.0, canDeposit=true, balances=[{free=4723846.89208129, locked=0.00000000, asset=BTC}, {free=4763368.68006011, asset=LTC, locked=0.00000000}], takerCommission=15.0, updateTime=1.23456789E8, accountType=SPOT, canTrade=true, sellerCommission=0.0, buyerCommission=0.0, canWithdraw=true, permissions=[SPOT]}]
12:21:48 AM Info    true
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your expected json string in binanace API is an array or just a single json data in your original post. But based on your for loop you might be expecting a json array. Let me know if my assumption is incorrect so i could update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I try to do this `encapsulate original json data with []` but I don't find the true code. can you write this code pls

Comment: it is already written in the sample code. see `jsonData`

Comment: I see your change in code JSON, but the code JSON is from binance API like that code in first post. I tell you if you have any method to change it like you do in code

Comment: See the updated answer. You just need to append "[]" in your data string. `data = "["+data+"]";`